# How to store the observation of each mixture component in R

Tags: r, mixture-model, mixture

I would like to fit a mixture model in R, manually. Then, I would like to store the observation for each component of the mixture model separately. That is, I would like my code to retain the observations drawn from each component. Here is an example of a mixture model using the EM-algorithm from [here](https://tinyheero.github.io/2016/01/03/gmm-em.html).

**I would like to know what are the observations of each mixture component. I need the value of these observations.**

```
e_step <- function(x, mu.vector, sd.vector, alpha.vector) {


 comp1.prod <- dnorm(x, mu.vector[1], sd.vector[1]) * alpha.vector[1]
  comp2.prod <- dnorm(x, mu.vector[2], sd.vector[2]) * alpha.vector[2]
  sum.of.comps <- comp1.prod + comp2.prod
  comp1.post <- comp1.prod / sum.of.comps
  comp2.post <- comp2.prod / sum.of.comps

  sum.of.comps.ln <- log(sum.of.comps, base = exp(1))
  sum.of.comps.ln.sum <- sum(sum.of.comps.ln)

  list("loglik" = sum.of.comps.ln.sum,
       "posterior.df" = cbind(comp1.post, comp2.post))
}

    m_step <- function(x, posterior.df) {
  comp1.n <- sum(posterior.df[, 1])
  comp2.n <- sum(posterior.df[, 2])

  comp1.mu <- 1/comp1.n * sum(posterior.df[, 1] * x)
  comp2.mu <- 1/comp2.n * sum(posterior.df[, 2] * x)

  comp1.var <- sum(posterior.df[, 1] * (x - comp1.mu)^2) * 1/comp1.n
  comp2.var <- sum(posterior.df[, 2] * (x - comp2.mu)^2) * 1/comp2.n

  comp1.alpha <- comp1.n / length(x)
  comp2.alpha <- comp2.n / length(x)

  list("mu" = c(comp1.mu, comp2.mu),
       "var" = c(comp1.var, comp2.var),
       "alpha" = c(comp1.alpha, comp2.alpha))
}
for (i in 1:50) {
  if (i == 1) {
    # Initialization
    e.step <- e_step(wait, wait.summary.df[["mu"]], wait.summary.df[["std"]],
                     wait.summary.df[["alpha"]])
    m.step <- m_step(wait, e.step[["posterior.df"]])
    cur.loglik <- e.step[["loglik"]]
    loglik.vector <- e.step[["loglik"]]
  } else {
    # Repeat E and M steps till convergence
    e.step <- e_step(wait, m.step[["mu"]], sqrt(m.step[["var"]]), 
                     m.step[["alpha"]])
    m.step <- m_step(wait, e.step[["posterior.df"]])
    loglik.vector <- c(loglik.vector, e.step[["loglik"]])

    loglik.diff <- abs((cur.loglik - e.step[["loglik"]]))
    if(loglik.diff < 1e-6) {
      break
    } else {
      cur.loglik <- e.step[["loglik"]]
    }
  }
}
loglik.vector
```